# Xampp phpmyadmin provides endless redirect error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

My Apache and MySQL instance starts up fine. For some reason, when I attempt to browse to phpmyadmin 
I am redirected to 
`http://localhost:8081/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/https:--localhost/phpmyadmin/`

I am sure where to look and the only thing I can think of is that I was trying to add a free SSL certificate to my localhost but it never worked.

This is my current settings.
[image]

**httpd.conf**

`Listen 8081
ServerName localhost:8081`

**httpd-ssl.conf**

`Listen 8081
ServerName localhost:8081`

`<VirtualHost _default_:8081>`

`#   General setup for the virtual host`

`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"`

`#ServerName www.example.com:8081`

`ServerName localhost:8081`

With the code above I get endless redirections 
but changing it to

`Listen 4433
ServerName localhost:4433`

`<VirtualHost _default_:4433>`

`#   General setup for the virtual host`

`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"`

`ServerName localhost:4433`

doesnt let my apache server start.

Appreciate it if I could get any insight regarding this.

REgards

Comment: You can try to re-install the XAMPP.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur Exactly what I didnt want to do